# Sort Mongo String field that includes date/time string

Tags: mongodb, sorting

Is it possible to sort a String field that contains a date/time ISOString in date/time order? Is the lexicographical order of date/time ISOStrings the same as the date/time order?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. It will be sorted in lexicographical order and in a lot of cases it will not be the same as normal date ordering.

You have to think twice before creating a schema for your collections no strings instead of dates/integers/floats. If you really made this mistake, update all your documents before it will be too much troubles.